# Spring boot REST Api JSON response - No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to build a RestAPI and return a JSONObject as response.
Therefore I created this controller:

```
    import java.util.List;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ApiController {
        @Autowired
        private AssemblyRepository assemblyRepo;

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> sendResponse(@RequestBody AppRequest request) {

            //do some stuff with the data from requestBody

            List<Assembly> assemblys = assemblyRepo.findAll();
            JSONArray t_sub_objlist = new JSONArray();
            for (Assembly a: assemblys) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                object.put("obj_type", a.getObjType());
                object.put("obj_key", a.getObjKey());
                t_sub_objlist.put(object);
            }
            response.put("t_sub_objlist", t_sub_objlist);
            return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

When I print the `response` to the console everything looks good: `{"t_sub_objlist":[{"obj_key":"MS","obj_type":"NT"},{"obj_key":"MV","obj_type":"NT"}]}`

But when I want to access the API from outside, the first time after restarting the server, I get this error message:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

And if i try again then this message always comes up:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here :)

Comment: Could you post what `response` is?

Comment: Sorry... I cut this out by accident ^^ `JSONObject response = new JSONObject();`

Comment: Why do you want to return a `JSONObject`? You can just create a POJO and return that, and it will be serialized into JSON. You could probably just  return `List<Assembly>`, depending on what `Assembly` looks like. But maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: `Assembly` is a very complex class and depending on the request I always need only a few different attributes. I thought it would be easier just to create a JSONObject "on-thy-fly" where I put in the needed key value pairs and return this.

Comment: Then try a Map<String, Object>.